# What does this code mean in typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Options {
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

It's quite complicate to me, 'key' has type string and any?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means objects that implement the Options interface are indexable. The indexable key is of type string, and can return any.

From https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html:

> Indexable Types
>
> We can describe types that we can “index into” like a[10], or ageMap["daniel"]. Indexable types have an index signature that describes the types we can use to index into the object, along with the corresponding return types when indexing.

Example:

```
interface StringArray {
    [index: number]: string;
}

let myArray: StringArray;
myArray = ["Bob", "Fred"];

let myStr: string = myArray[0];
```

Comment: So basically, this `Options` interface allows you to add any keys with any kind of value. For the ones that you know will be there, you can still add the typesafe field definitions on top of that.

Comment: Thank you all! Now I understand this.